# Summing all tuples with same keys (Implementing Haskell Data.Map.fromListWith)

Tags: dictionary, haskell, tuples

I want to sum the values of the tuples that have the same key.

For instance,

```
foo = [(True, 0), (True, 1), (False, 2), (True, -1), (False,4)] :: [(Bool, Int)]
putStrLn . show $ sumTuples foo
```

should show 
`[(False,6),(True,0)]`.

Surely, this is easily doable with `Data.Map.fromListWith`:

```hs
sumTuples :: (Ord a, Num b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sumTuples = Map.toList . Map.fromListWith (+)
```

but I want to implement it without the help of `Data.Map`.

Using filters, I could solve it like this:

```hs
sumByFilter :: [(Bool, Int)] -> [(Bool, Int)]
sumByFilter xs =
  let trues = filter((==True) . fst) xs
      falses = filter((==False) . fst) xs
      summing = sum . map snd
  in [(True, summing trues), (False, summing falses)]
```

or with folds:

```hs
sumByUglyFold :: [(Bool, Int)] -> [(Bool, Int)]
sumByUglyFold =
  let initial = [(True, 0), (False, 0)]
  in foldl foldingFxn initial

foldingFxn :: [(Bool,Int)] -> (Bool, Int) -> [(Bool, Int)]
foldingFxn [(_, truAcc), (_, falseAcc)] (bool, val)
  | bool      = [(True, truAcc + val), (False, falseAcc)]
  | otherwise = [(True, truAcc), (False, falseAcc + val)]
```

**However, in both instances, I have hardcoded the first argument as a boolean. However, I want to be able to do this for any not predefined key -- surely if I had string keys, I couldn't pattern match against all of them.**

*How can I make my code general?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to sort by the key, then group by it, and then sum each group:

```
sumThem = map sumGroup . groupBy fstEq . sortOn fst
  where
    sumGroup (x:xs) = (fst x, sum $ map snd (x:xs))
    sumGroup _ = error "This can never happen - groupBy cannot return empty groups"

    fstEq (a, _) (b, _) = a == b
```

Note that sorting is an essential operation here, because `groupBy` only groups *consequitive* elements.

Comment: Some tips for future readers: `fstEq` can be written as ``(==) `on` fst`` (with `Data.Function.on`) and `sortOn f` is less efficient than `sortBy (comparing f)` (with `Data.Ord.comparing`) for trivial functions like `fst`, because it caches the key being compared, but more efficient for costly `f`.

Comment: @JonPurdy I specifically didn't want to mention all that for the sake of keeping the answer simple and to the point.

Comment: I understand and agree that’s the right move, just adding some supplementary info.